# Using a 4-Pole Relay to trigger a switch for a detection circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, relay

sorry not super hot on electronics and hope I can explain myself.

I am building a model railway and use a device from a company called NCE called a [BD20](https://ncedcc.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201254549-BD20-Block-Detector). It is a simple induction switch - when there is current/draw on the looped wire, it connects the GND + Logic pins making a circuit.

This is connected to a detection device (called a [AIU01](https://ncedcc.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200933435-Auxiliary-Input-Unit-AIU01)) which detects the circuit and sends a message to the computer.

The AIU01 outputs +5v on each of the 14 input pins (I can detect 14 blocks) and expects this to be closed to GND (COMMON).

I could not get enough BD20 units and purchased a different induction detector ([BD4N](https://www.digitrax.com/products/detection-signaling/bd4n/) from Digitrax). It supports 4 input blocks to detect. However, it creates a circuit by looping the COMMON to the appropriate logic PIN but in this case, the COMMON is +ve and the logic pins are all -ve. Also the COMMON requires a power source.

So I cannot just connect the two of them.

I was thinking, could I use a 4-Pole Relay (one of the ones that work with Arduino) but I am not sure how I would wire the BD4N to the relay and supply a voltage to one of the RELAY pins that would connect to the COMMON on the BD4N and then the 4 outputs from the BD4N would connect to the input pins on the RELAY?

Or any other suggestions?

Also, model railroading uses DCC as an AC waveform (+13v) - can I use this as power into the VCC line of the Relay?

[image]

Comment: Put a circuit diagram in your question please.

Comment: Thanks RoyC. Added a diagram, not sure if it helps.

Comment: Could you add a link to the relay you are considering? I suspect you mean something like a 4-relay module (since you mention Arduino and a VCC line), with each of the four relays corresponding to an output on the BD4N. A four-pole relay is a different thing which has four sets of contacts that operate at the same time. Also, VCC typically refers to a DC voltage so the alternating DCC waveform is probably not suitable, but a rectifier might help.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I could use something like https://www.jaycar.co.nz/arduino-compatible-4-channel-12v-relay-module/p/XC4440

Comment: @trevleyb This is a highly specialized area. I think you may need another enthusiast, but one more familiar with the electronic and signalling details, to help sort out a solution using existing products and/or using the least number of separately designed circuit adaptations. It's going to be a tough fit here. (Not impossible, just tough.) Are their enthusiast forums with an electronics bend to them that you might consider?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I may just have to bite-the-bullet and find another 8 of the original BD20 units as I know they just work. I kind of thought if the BD4N can create a circuit and I can trigger a relay to also then create a circuit, then it should work.

Comment: You need to find a small relay which can be driven by the output of the BD4N. To do this check the coil specification of the relay you are considering and the output drive capability of the BD4N. The advice to find a specialist within the community is fg

Comment: if these are the relay modules with the opto-isolated inout then yes these could be used . actually you could just use opto-isolators instead.